# OracleDatareader seems to execute an update statement

Tags: oracle, ado.net, odp.net

I am using oracle client 11.2.0 
Dll version 4.112.3.0

We have a page in our application where people can give a sql statement and retreive results. basically do an oracle command.executereader

Recently one of my team members gave an update statement as a test and it actually performed an update on a record!!!!

Anyone who has encountered this?

Regards
Sid.

Answer (score 1):

It is a normal (albeit a bit unsettling) behavior. ExecuteReader is expected to execute the sql command provided as CommandText and build a DbDataReader that you use to loop over the results.
If the command doesn't return any row to read is not something that the reader should prevent in any case. And so it is not expected that it checks if your command is really a SELECT statement.
Think for example if you pass a stored procedure name or if you have multiple sql batch to execute. (INSERT followed by a SELECT)

I think that the biggest problem here is the fact that you allow an arbitrary sql command typed by your users to reach the database engine. A very big hole in security. You should, at least, execute some analysis on the query text before submitting the code to the database engine.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Steve. Your reader will execute any command, and might get a bit confused if it's not a select and doesn't return a result set.

To prevent people from modifying anything, create a new user, grant select only (no update, no delete, no insert) on your tables to that user (`grant select on tablename to seconduser`). Then, log in as seconduser, and, create synonyms for your tables (`create synonym tablename for realowner.tablename`). Have your application use the seconduser when connecting to the DB. This should prevent people from "hacking" your site. If you want to be of the safe side, grant no permissions but `create session` to the second user to prevent him from creating tables, dropping your views and similar stuff (I'd guess your executereader won't allow DDL, but test it to make sure).